# Viewing Inline images in Mutt mail on macos/OSX

Tags: html-email, macos-catalina, mutt, inline-images, w3m

Is there any way to see inline images in mutt pager view in terminal?
I've tried w3m but it requires w3m-img which seems not for macos/osx.
Can anyone suggest if it's possible to integrate **imgcat**(avaiable in iterm2) in mailcap?
Please suggest complete steps/any solution for displaying images in terminal for mutt mail agent.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use `imgcat` to show images directly in built-in pager using mailcap and autoview at least from my findings.

Try following line in Your mailcap file

```
image/*; (clear && imgcat %s && read -N 1); needsterminal
```

Then hit `v` to show attachments, select any image attachment and press `<enter>`.
To get back to mutt, just press any key.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, do you know any other way to view it directly? Means not as an attachment but like in mail body like Gmail?

Comment: I tried it several times and different approaches before and it didn’t work. But you can try asking on #mutt #neomutt channels on Freenode. There’s more brainpower. You can reflect your findings here later.